# C++ storage class and qualifier rules for declarations vs definitions

Tags: c++, c++11, header, initialization, declaration

Admittedly the reason for doing this has subsided now that C++11 has got rid of that nasty rule whereby- I think it was declaring static const int/char/enum was allowed you to initialise in the header, but for all other types you couldnt. Because of this I wanted to try and summarise declaring and defining conventions for C++.

Would someone be able to take what I attempt/do below and extend it for whatever I miss/get incorrect. I would like to summarise all the "rules" for declarations and definitions for the various static/const/int/non-int variables. Ideally this could be put in to a table of some sorts with 3 columns: type of data/declaring/defining- but I dont know how to do that on here:

**static data member** (Declaring)

- Only provide the type and the name, do not initialize because multiple files using the same header would end up producing more than one copy.

**static data member** (Defining)

- Initialise the variable in the source file. Do not have to repeat the word "static" in the source file definition.

**const data member** (Declaring)

- Declared but not initialized in the header file using keyword const.

**const data member** (Defining)

- Must be initialized using an initializer list in the constructor.

**static and const** data member (Declaring)

- Declared in header file using keywords static and const but not initialized.

**static and const** data member (Defining)

- Defined in source file. Do not need to use keywords static and const (??).

NB: I understand pre-C++11 int/enum/char used to have a special rule regarding static (or was it static const?), was it they *could* be initialised in the header??

- Rules for global variables
- Rules for mutable
- Rules for extern
- Does volatile follow exactly the same rules as "const"? A static volatile would follow the conventions for static data members etc?

Comment: I guess you haven't yet heard about C++11 allowing in-class initialization of non-static data members.

Comment: You need to review your sources. Additionally, I am not 100% sure that you understand what *declare* and *define* really mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C++ standard, `const` and `volatile` are nearly always "next to each other". In particular, `volatile` and `const` have the same order of precedence and "need for location".

Pre C++11 (and of course also in C++11) you can initialize `const static` of simple types (that is, for example `int` or closely related types, but not other types (those that have a constructor, fro example).

Comment: The rules for providing a value to a static const member are a bit more complex, existence of *constructor* is not the criterion, but rather that the static const member is of *integral* or *enumeration* types (not even `const char*`)